# How do I call a SecureStore Credential by name rather than by type?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, credentials, secure-store

I am using SecureStore for storing the data needed to make SQL queries from a Sharepoint webpart without having to hard-code the data in the config file.  I have created the following fields in the target application:

```
Username   type = Username
Password   type = Password
Server     type = Key
DB         type = Generic
```

When I attempt to retrieve the data from the SecureStore via my SecureStoreProxy.CS I am using the following code:

```
 var db = from c in credentials
      where c.CredentiaType == SecureStoreCredentialType.Generic
      select c.Credential;
```

What if I have more than one Generic Credential Type?  What if I have this one named db and another named db2, for example?  How do I call the SecureStore credential by name (db) rather than by type(Generic)?

Update:  Here is the link to the example I used.  Everything works fine, BUT you may notice that this code calls the credentials by name rather than by type.  My question is how do I call the credentials by name, rather than by type?
[ExampleLink](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20549.sharepoint-2010-storing-database-connection-settings-in-the-secure-store.aspx)

Comment: I have something like this somewhere, let me see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had followed this TechNet article on creating a Secure Store proxy: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20110.sharepoint-retrieving-credentials-from-the-secure-store-application-using-c.aspx.

After implementing that in my console application, I had this in my code, it relied on magic stringing the connection name, where "SPOSiteCreator" was the name of the item in the Secure Store:

```
var settings = SecureStoreProxy.GetCredentialsFromSecureStoreService("SPOSiteCreator", SecureStoreProxy.CredentialType.Domain);
var user = settings.UserName;
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in settings.Password)
  securePassword.AppendChar(c);
securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
```

We didn't do much with it because we abandoned this as we were moving off prem. I did test this and it worked in my console application, connecting with the secure store username and password.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where you use the name rather than type.  Can you explain a bit please?